# Sample space size of an experiment with $n$ trials

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I'm reading Mathematical Statistics from Wackerly and there's a confusing bit in the chapter on the hypergeometric probability distribution. There's a population $S$ of size $N$, the experiment is selecting a random sample of size $n$. The author says:

> Each sample point can be characterized by an $n$-tuple whose elements correspond to a selection of $n$ elements from the total of $N$. If each element in the population were numbered from 1 to $N$, the sample point indicating the selection of items 5, 7, 8, 64, 17, $\ldots$, 87 would appear as the $n$-tuple $(5, 7, 8, 64, 17, \ldots, 87)$. The total number of sample points in $S$, therefore, will equal the number of ways of selecting a subset of $n$ elements from a population of $N$, or $N\choose{n}$.

How is it $N\choose{n}$ if sample points are tuples, not sets? Should we also consider the elements' ordering, in which case the sample space size is $N\choose{n}$$*n!$ ?

Comment: As I understand, You are right. For each selection of $n$ elements from population of size $N$, (for example $1,2,3,\dots, n$) we have exactly one sample point, which is unique (i.e, $(1,2,3,\dots, n)$). So we have $N*(N-1)*\dots*(N+1-n)$ sample points.